# OGC CSW Filter Capabilities Comparison Operators

Tags: filter, ogc, getcapabilities, csw

I'm a bit confused with OGC standards related to CSW GetCapabilities for Filter Encoding.
A typical CSW GetCapabilities Request
http://www.geocatalogue.fr/api-public/servicesRest?service=CSW&request=GetCapabilities&AcceptVersion=2.0.2
will return allowed ComparisonOperators for filtering, typically :

```
<ogc:ComparisonOperator>GreaterThanEqualTo</ogc:ComparisonOperator>
```

However OGC standard for filter encoding https://www.ogc.org/standards/filter defines comparison operator being in the form of :

```
<xsd:element name="PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo" type="ogc:BinaryComparisonOpType" substitutionGroup="ogc:comparisonOps"/>
```

Which schema should be used for OGC CSW filter_capabilities ? GreaterThanEqualTo or PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo ?

Comment: It's a known issue, GeoNetwork CSW responses for example have in comments `<!--  GreaterThanOrEqualTo is in OGC Filter Spec, GreaterThanEqualTo is in OGC CSW schema  -->` then offer both `<ogc:ComparisonOperator>GreaterThanEqualTo</ogc:ComparisonOperator>
<ogc:ComparisonOperator>GreaterThanOrEqualTo</ogc:ComparisonOperator>`  making the response invalid.

Comment: If your service only offers `GreaterThanEqualTo` then that's what you will need to use.

Comment: Ok but `GreaterThanOrEqualTo` does not exist in the OGC Filter Spec, it should be `PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo`, shouldn't it ?

Comment: Baring OGC changing the schema to also add or to replace the erroneous values, you should use `GreaterThanEqualTo` .